# No esta definido Nombre cuando recorro con each

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy recogiendo datos en **inputs** con un `each`, cuando intento agregarlo en una variable me dice que nombre no esta definido al parecer tengo una error de sintaxis.

```js
function guardar_testimonio(){
    $("#infotestis").each(function(){
        var nombre = $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(0).val();
        var testimoniouno= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(1).val();
        var testimoniodos= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(2).val();;
        var compania= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(3).val();;
        var lugar= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(4).val();;
        console.log(nombre+" "+testimoniouno+" "+testimoniodos+" "+compania+" "+lugar);
    });
 
    var datos_formulario = "nombres=" + nombre;
        // "&testimoniouno="+testimoniouno+ "&testimoniodos="+testimoniodos +"&compania="+ compania + "&lugar="+ lugar;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../dashmin/php/agregar.php',
            data: datos_formulario,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (objeto) {

            },
            success: function (json) {     


            },
            error: function (e) {

            },
            complete: function (objeto, exito, error) {

            }
        });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infotestis">
      <h5>Nombre:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Alejando Sallustro">
       <h5>Testimonio:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Una inversión acorde"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="a estos tiempos">
       <h5>Compañia:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="CEO, Sallustro &amp; Cía.">
       <h5>Lugar:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Asuncion">
       <h5>Perfil:</h5> <img src="" alt="">
        <button onclick="guardar_testimonio()" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar<div class="ripple-container"></div></button>
                                                
</div>
```

Comment: `nombre` está definido solo dentro de la función del `each`. Saca `nombre` afuera o mete el resto del código dentro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu caso su `each` no está haciendo nada ya que estás accediendo a los valores de cada `input` directamente, simplemente quítalo.

Cabe resaltar que el método `.parent()` no es necesario para tu selector ya que estas seleccionando elementos que son hijos directos de `#infotestis`

```js
function guardar_testimonio(){
        var nombre = $("#infotestis").find("input").eq(0).val();
        var testimoniouno= $("#infotestis").find("input").eq(1).val();
        var testimoniodos= $("#infotestis").find("input").eq(2).val();
        var compania= $("#infotestis").find("input").eq(3).val();
        var lugar= $("#infotestis").find("input").eq(4).val();
        console.log(nombre+" "+testimoniouno+" "+testimoniodos+" "+compania+" "+lugar);
 
    var datos_formulario = "nombres=" + nombre;
        // "&testimoniouno="+testimoniouno+ "&testimoniodos="+testimoniodos +"&compania="+ compania + "&lugar="+ lugar;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../dashmin/php/agregar.php',
            data: datos_formulario,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (objeto) {

            },
            success: function (json) {     


            },
            error: function (e) {

            },
            complete: function (objeto, exito, error) {

            }
        });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infotestis">
                                                <h5>Nombre:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Alejando Sallustro">
                                                <h5>Testimonio:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Una inversión acorde"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="a estos tiempos">
                                                <h5>Compañia:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="CEO, Sallustro &amp; Cía.">
                                                <h5>Lugar:</h5> <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Asuncion">
                                                <h5>Perfil:</h5> <img src="" alt="">
                                                <button onclick="guardar_testimonio()" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar<div class="ripple-container"></div></button>
                                                
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En javascript, los alcances de las variables estan definidos por la funcion en la que estan definidas:

```
$("#infotestis").each(function(){
    var scope = 1;
    console.log(scope); //imprime 1
});
console.log(scope); //imprime undefined
```

Por otra parte, el metodo `each(function(){...})` de jQuery ejecuta una funcion por cada elemento que cumpla con el selector que le precede. En tu caso basta con ejecutar el cuerpo de la funcion sin `each`:

```
function guardar_testimonio(){
    var nombre = $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(0).val();
    var testimoniouno= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(1).val();
    var testimoniodos= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(2).val();;
    var compania= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(3).val();;
    var lugar= $("#infotestis").parent().find("input").eq(4).val();;
    console.log(nombre+" "+testimoniouno+" "+testimoniodos+" "+compania+" "+lugar);

    var datos_formulario = "nombres=" + nombre;
        // "&testimoniouno="+testimoniouno+ "&testimoniodos="+testimoniodos +"&compania="+ compania + "&lugar="+ lugar;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../dashmin/php/agregar.php',
            data: datos_formulario,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (objeto) {

            },
            success: function (json) {     


            },
            error: function (e) {

            },
            complete: function (objeto, exito, error) {

            }
        });

}
```